# $E = A^C \cap B^C$, is my answer good?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Could anyone tell me if my answer is correct regarding this set(complement) question. As to confirm myself that I understand it or not.

$U = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15\}$.

$A = \{2,4,6,8,10,12,14\}$,
$B = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$.

Answer i got :

$E = A^C \cap B^C$.

$E = \{1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15\} \cap \{6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15\}$.

$E = \{9,11,13,15\}.$

Can anyone tell me if my answer is good or not?

Comment: Please use MathJax for formatting. [Here's a tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Should be $\require{cancel}$$A^c = \{1,3,5,6,\cancel 8,\color{green}9,11,13,15\}$.  Had you *MEANT* for that $\color{green}9$ to actually be the $\cancel 8$. You would have ended up with the $8$ in the final answer and not the $9$.  So... I'm assuming that the $8$ was a typo and you actually meant $9$?  If so it's correct.

Comment: Oh... we missed the $7$ in the final answer.  $7$ is in both.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The general idea is correct, but you made some small mistakes.

$E = A^c \cap B^c$

$E=\{1,3,5,7, \mathbf{9},11,13,15\} \cap \{6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15\}$

$E=\{\mathbf{7},9,11,13,15\}$

Comment: ah thank you. scary how easy it is to  miss something so small.

Comment: Please use MathJax for formatting.

Comment: @ActuallyFritz Fixed.